# Adding a table to the Membership-database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-membership

I am using the membership-database for usermanagement.
The layout looks as follows:

[image]

As you can see I added a new table "Downloads".
In this table I want to store some additional information.

I made a class:

```
public class DownloadInformation
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int UserId { get; set;}
    public string UserName { get; set;}
    public string Filename { get; set;}
    public string UserIpAddress { get; set;}
    public DateTime DownloadDate { get; set; }
}
```

In my ApplicationDbContext I did the following :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        var idUser = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("UserView");
        idUser.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        idUser.Property(p => p.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("Password");
        idUser.Property(p => p.SecurityStamp).HasColumnName("PasswordSalt");
        idUser.Property(p => p.UserName).HasColumnName("UserName");

        var appUser = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("UserView");
        appUser.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        appUser.Property(p => p.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("Password");
        appUser.Property(p => p.SecurityStamp).HasColumnName("PasswordSalt");
        appUser.Property(p => p.UserName).HasColumnName("UserName");
        appUser.Property(p => p.Email).HasColumnName("Email");


        var download = modelBuilder.Entity<DownloadInformation>().ToTable("Downloads");
        download.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        download.Property(p => p.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
        download.Property(p => p.UserIpAddress).HasColumnName("UserIpAddress");
        download.Property(p => p.UserName).HasColumnName("UserName");
        download.Property(p => p.Filename).HasColumnName("Filename");
        download.Property(p => p.DownloadDate).HasColumnName("DownloadDate");
    }
}
```

But when I try to do the following :

```
using (ApplicationDbContext app = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            DownloadInformation downloadInfo = new DownloadInformation() { UserId = user.UserId, UserName = user.UserName, UserIpAddress = user.IpAddress, Filename = document.FilePath, DownloadDate = DateTime.Now };

            app.Download.Add(downloadInfo);
            app.SaveChanges();
        }
```

When I compile this, I get the following error :

'CustomerPortalDomain.Entities.ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'Download' and no extension method 'Download' accepting a first argument of type 'CustomerPortalDomain.Entities.ApplicationDbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What did I forget? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you didn't add any 'Download' Property to your ApplicationDbContext

```
public DbSet<DownloadInformation> Download{ get; set; }
```